# FSharp compiler not including appSettings section in the app.config (FSharp.Configuration)

Tags: configuration, f#, appsettings

I am using the FSharp.Configuration Library.

I noticed sometimes FSharp compiler generates the programName.exe.config but it doesn't include the appSettings section I added in. In order to see the appSettings section in the output config file, I have to remove the startup section and runtime section. Strangely, if I add back the startup and runtime section now, the FSharp compiler won't have any problem outputting the complete config file (containing appSettings, startup and runtime).

This doesn't happen all the time. I can't find a logical reason how it can happen.

Has anyone experienced the same thing as well?

I am using VS2013 with up to date patch (as of 2015-04-08). I also have the System.Configuration reference added and included in the code.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case appsettings section was not copied every time and it was solved by switching from Debug to Release configuration.
In Release configuration it works fine.